# Why is my discord bot not starting after I try and add a new command?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make a bot that has very basic commands, I followed a guide online but it wasn't clear about how to add more commands, so I tried copy pasting some things around, but it just would not even remotely work.

Not too sure what's going on here, I tried messing around with the code to no avail, every time I try and run it, it just spews out errors such as syntax errors:

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');

var logger = require('winston');

var auth = require('./auth.json');

// Configure logger settings

logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);

logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {

colorize: true
});

logger.level = 'debug';

// Initialize Discord Bot

var bot = new Discord.Client({

token: auth.token,

autorun: true

});

bot.on('ready', function (evt) {

logger.info('Connected');

logger.info('Logged in as: ');

logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});

bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {

// Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command

// It will listen for messages that will start with `!`

if (message.substring(0, 1) == ';') {

    var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');

    var cmd = args[0];


    args = args.splice(1);

    switch(cmd) {

        // !ping

        case 'ping':

            bot.sendMessage({

                to: channelID,

                message: 'Pong!'

    switch(cmd) {

        // ;test

        case 'test':

            bot.sendMessage({

                to: channelID,

                message: 'test!'

        break;

        // Just add any case commands if you want to..

     }

 }
});
```

Comment: The errors will tell you (or us) what's wrong. Unfortunately you didn't include them, and I it's a waste of time to do what the computer already did for you and to guess or try to identify syntax issues ourselves. So, to let us help you, please include the error.

Comment: Anyway it sounds like you don't know JavaScript. It will be very painful to write a Discord bot without knowing how to program in JavaScript (and frustrating for people you ask for help), "copying things around" without understanding what they do will not yield the expected results! I recommend learning basic JavaScript programming first before continuing.

Comment: You're using discord.io, not discord.js. The users this question is being exposed to will likely not know how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You did not include any errors. We can't help you solve your error without the logs.

From what I have and my past experience. I would call `ready` with `once()` and not `on()`. Second thing, if I remember correctly, the `on("message")` event only references `Message` and not everything you put in your functions. Start by fixing all of this, including an error log, and maybe someone will be able to help you :)